# Python: find which objects are marked for deletion by gc?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, python-2.6

Let's say that I get following output from `gc.get_count()`

```
gc.get_count()
(2, 1, 0)
```

What I want to know is that which are these three objects that `gc.get_count()` is counting? Can I get their id? their name? size etc.? (I do know about the threshold value and the 3 stage collection in python).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `gc.get_objects()` instead.

See the [Python Garbage Collector interface](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/gc.html) documentation.

Comment: could you please elaborate on how can I filter out the objects of interest from the result of gc.get_objects()? It returns a list of over 3k elements