# python's gc - get objects from get_count

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I am trying to understand the discrepancy between values returned from `gc.get_count` and `gc.get_objects()`.

First, the doc (https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/gc.html) says:

> gc.get_count()
>
> > Return the current collection counts as a tuple of (count0, count1,
> > count2).

> gc.get_objects(generation=None)
>
> > Returns a list of all objects tracked by the collector, excluding the list returned. If generation is not None, return only the objects tracked by the collector that are in that generation.

now, on a simple REPL I run:

```
> import gc
> gc.get_count()
(692, 1, 1)
> len(gc.get_objects())
6372
> len(gc.get_objects(0))
771
> len(gc.get_objects(1))
490
> len(gc.get_objects(2))
5111
> gc.get_count()
(693, 1, 1)
```

So from `get_count` there are around 700 objects in the three generations combined.
However `get_objects` return >6k objects.
I have tried to look into `DEBUG_SAVEALL` but it didn't seem to correlate to any of the numbers (not in `get_count` and not in `get_objects`).

My questions are:

1. Why the discrepancy? What is the actual difference between objects in `get_objects` and objects tracked in `get_count`? There are these two questions on stackoverflow: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627919/python-find-which-objects-are-marked-for-deletion-by-gc) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57462037/what-are-count0-count1-and-count2-values-returned-by-the-python-gc-get-count) but they don't seem to answer the discrepancy.
2. How do I actually get the objects which are referenced in `get_count` (for a specific generation of it)?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that `get_count()` returns the number of objects that were collected during the last cycle, `get_objects()` is the objects that are still live.

Comment: @barmar - it's different, not the number of objects that were collected, but number of collections (and it's more refined than that, see my answer below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I have read a bit into the CPython implementation (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/gcmodule.c) and this is what I've learned:

#### 1)

Basically `get_count` (impl here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/gcmodule.c#L1636-L1645) measures the amount of collections happened in a one level lower generation until that generation itself gets collected (See here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/gcmodule.c#L1211-L1212).

So for example, when gen 0 (first gen) is collected, the count for gen 1 increases by 1.
The count for gen 0 increases upon allocation, and decreases on deallocation (the collection starts when the `#allocations - #deallocations > threashold`).

This answers question (1) - the discrepancy is because they are totally different things.

---

#### 2)

Now that question 1 is answered, question 2 is actually not relevant when asked as is.

However, we might ask a different question which is *"how do I track which objects are collected for a specific generation?"*.

With Python 3.8 this is possible since the interface of `get_objects` has changed and it's possible to get the objects that "belong" to a specific generation.
With that in mind, one can register a callback (via the `gc.callbacks.append(callback_method)`) that will track the collection of that specific gen by getting the objects before they are cleaned (but note that you don't want to actually strong reference these objects or else you will change behaviour just by measuring), getting them afterwards, and comparing the results.

---

I will leave this answer unaccepted for some time to give chance for other answers, since I'm answering my own question.